# How to set value for input="color"

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set value for input="color" when typing in `input(.color-scheme__log-input-text)`, for example if I type `#060606` - this color have to be applied to `input="color"`

как изменить цвет input="color" при вводе значения в `color-scheme__log-input-text`

```js
$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("keypress", function() {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.val().length < 7) {
    if (self.val()[0] != "#") {
      self.val("#" + self.val());
    }
    var color = self.val();
    $(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.color-scheme {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.color-scheme__container {
  display: flex;
}

.color-scheme__item {
  width: 100%;
}

.color-scheme__column:first-of-type {
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.color-scheme__column:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-scheme__input-color {
  display: block;
  height: auto !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140px;
}

.color-scheme__color-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-scheme__input-color-pick {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -7px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-scheme__container">
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <input type="text" class="color-scheme__input-color color-scheme__log-input-text" name="login_but_text">
  </div>
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <div class="color-scheme__color-container">
      <input id="input-color-6" class="color-scheme__input-color-pick color-scheme__log-btn-text" value="#000" type="color">
    </div>
    <label class="color-scheme__input-color-label" for="input-color-6">click to pick color</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First `self.val().length <= 7` should be less or equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("keyup", function() {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.val().length <= 7) {
    if (self.val()[0] != "#") {
      self.val("#" + self.val());
    }
    var color = self.val();
    $("#input-color-6").val(color);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.color-scheme {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.color-scheme__container {
  display: flex;
}

.color-scheme__item {
  width: 100%;
}

.color-scheme__column:first-of-type {
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.color-scheme__column:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-scheme__input-color {
  display: block;
  height: auto !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140px;
}

.color-scheme__color-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-scheme__input-color-pick {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -7px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-scheme__container">
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <input type="text" class="color-scheme__input-color color-scheme__log-input-text" name="login_but_text">
  </div>
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <div class="color-scheme__color-container">
      <input id="input-color-6" class="color-scheme__input-color-pick color-scheme__log-btn-text" value="" type="color">
    </div>
    <label class="color-scheme__input-color-label" for="input-color-6">click to pick color</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should be `if (self.val().length <= 7)` and use `keyup` instead of `keypress` because if you use `keypress` the key you've just be pressed is not yet added to the current value..

Comment: It doesn't work, I type in input #060606 but input='color' still black color

Comment: @DimaVleskov i've tried yellow `#ffff00` and maroon `#800000` and they are working..

Comment: i tried this colors yellow #ffff00 and maroon #800000 too, and everything works but some color no, I'm a little bit confused

Comment: i've search `#060606` and the result is black. Try a different value. and a valid one.

Comment: @DimaVleskov i've tried a random like `#ff8212`  and it displays it.

Comment: everything works well now, can you tell me how to enter only 6 charecter in input?  #ff8212 - no more

Answer (score 2):

You can set this on [change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) for the textbox.
I have added below part to the snippet below.

```
   $(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("change", function() {
    var color = $(this).val();
    $("#input-color-6").value = color;
    $(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
  });
```

```js
$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("keypress", function() {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.val().length < 7) {
    if (self.val()[0] != "#") {
      self.val("#" + self.val());
    }
    var color = self.val();
    $(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
    
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

   $(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("change", function() {
var color = $(this).val();
$("#input-color-6").value = color;
$(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
  });
```

```css
.color-scheme {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.color-scheme__container {
  display: flex;
}

.color-scheme__item {
  width: 100%;
}

.color-scheme__column:first-of-type {
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.color-scheme__column:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-scheme__input-color {
  display: block;
  height: auto !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140px;
}

.color-scheme__color-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-scheme__input-color-pick {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -7px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-scheme__container">
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <input type="text" class="color-scheme__input-color color-scheme__log-input-text" name="login_but_text">
  </div>
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <div class="color-scheme__color-container">
      <input id="input-color-6" class="color-scheme__input-color-pick color-scheme__log-btn-text" value="#000" type="color">
    </div>
    <label class="color-scheme__input-color-label" for="input-color-6">click to pick color</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `keyup` and not `keypress` because `keypress` will fire your code before the value of the key your pressing has been entered into the input.

`$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("keyup", function()`

**Demo**

```js
$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("keyup", function() {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.val().length <= 7) {
    if (self.val()[0] != "#") {
      self.val("#" + self.val());
    }
    var color = self.val();
    $("#input-color-6").val(color);
  } else {
  self.val(self.val().slice(0,-1))
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.color-scheme {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.color-scheme__container {
  display: flex;
}

.color-scheme__item {
  width: 100%;
}

.color-scheme__column:first-of-type {
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.color-scheme__column:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-scheme__input-color {
  display: block;
  height: auto !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140px;
}

.color-scheme__color-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-scheme__input-color-pick {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -7px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-scheme__container">
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <input type="text" class="color-scheme__input-color color-scheme__log-input-text" name="login_but_text">
  </div>
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <div class="color-scheme__color-container">
      <input id="input-color-6" class="color-scheme__input-color-pick color-scheme__log-btn-text" value="#000" type="color">
    </div>
    <label class="color-scheme__input-color-label" for="input-color-6">click to pick color</label>
  </div>
</div>
```